# How to iterate over this json file in javaScript?

Tags: arrays, json, iterator

I know this question has been asked a lot, and I've already went through to so many contents about this subject, but I'm still looking for something more useful...well my question is how to iterate over the following json file, I mean I need to get all the values which are into the variable, also there are some arrays into it I need it values too. I'm newbie at javascript so that it's been quite hard to find out the solution by myself.

This is the Variable:

```
{
    "type": "draw2d.shape.basic.Oval",
    "id": "5b4c74b0-96d1-1aa3-7eca-bbeaed5fffd7",
    "x": 237,
    "y": 236,
    "width": 93,
    "height": 38,
    "alpha": 1,
    "selectable": true,
    "draggable": true,
    "angle": 0,
    "userData": {},
    "cssClass": "draw2d_shape_basic_Oval",
    "ports": [],
    "bgColor": "rgba(255,255,0,undefined)",
    "color": "rgba(27,27,27,1)",
    "stroke": 1,
    "radius": 0,
    "dasharray": null
  },
  {
    "type": "draw2d.shape.basic.Rectangle",
    "id": "354fa3b9-a834-0221-2009-abc2d6bd852a",
    "x": 225,
    "y": 97,
    "width": 201,
    "height": 82,
    "alpha": 1,
    "selectable": true,
    "draggable": true,
    "angle": 0,
    "userData": {},
    "cssClass": "draw2d_shape_basic_Rectangle",
    "ports": [],
    "bgColor": "rgba(0,255,0,undefined)",
    "color": "rgba(27,27,27,1)",
    "stroke": 1,
    "radius": 2,
    "dasharray": null
  },
```

Comment: Have you tried a `for` loop?

Comment: Could you give a code sample. Just what you have so far.